# Would it be possible to utilize the higgs boson field in order to generate more inertia?

Tags: higgs

Since the Higgs boson provides mass would it be possible at all to use the field in a way that generates more inertia? For example, could we utilize it in a way to make a vehicle or something smaller move with more inertia than it would previously be able to?

Comment: This Higgs _boson_ does not "provide mass". The Higgs _mechanism_ gives mass.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the Higgs boson provides mass would it be possible at all to use the field in a way that generates more inertia?

No.

> For example, could we utilize it in a way to make a vehicle or something smaller move with more inertia than it would previously be able to?

No.